# ActiveMQ redelivery times per queue?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have ActiveMQ 5.10.0 and configured the receiver and the broker the same:
tcp://localhost:61666?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=0&jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=5&jms.redeliveryPolicy.initialRedeliveryDelay=5000&jms.redeliveryPolicy.useExponentialBackOff=true&jms.redeliveryPolicy.backOffMultiplier=2.0&jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true&jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveryDelay=180

When there is only one message on the queue that throws an exception, it is redelivered as expected, after 5s, 10, 20, 40 and 80. then it is placed on the deadletterque.

When multiple messages are placed on the queue, the times are doubled, not for the each message, but for the queue. I expect the maximum time is 180 seconds, but message 1 is retried 170 s after message 2 and the next message is retried after 340s. The next message is after 680s...
Did I find a bug in ActiveMQ or is my configuration wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To keep the order, the message is retried and will block that consumer. So if you put two "bad" messages at the queue, the first will retry for 180 seconds, then the second one will be retried for 180 seconds and so forth. This is the expected behaviour to keep message order.

Comment: I doubt if it is the message order, first MQ tries message 1, then 2, then 3 and then again 1 etc. How can I disable message order?

Comment: @Petter, is that true when `jms.nonBlockingRedelivery` is true?  I thought that was the point of that URI option...

Comment: No. nonBlocking works for redelivery and should solve this. Ahh, I see now that it's included in the URL in by OP. At least that option works in Spring DMLC and in derived tools like Apache Camel. So it should do the work. Seems like it's not really rocking when using plain MessageListener and single session though. Depends a bit, as it seems.